# How do I auto-focus an EOS M when stopped down to kill the ambient?

Tags: flash, autofocus, focus, studio-lighting

I'm trying to do take some portraits with two off-camera strobes. I want a dark background, so I'm using a high f-stop and high ISO to kill the ambient, relying on the strobes to light the model.

But in this situation the viewfinder goes dark and the AF stops working and it's too dark to manually focus.

Models are my children (who won't sit still:-), so I can't really 'pre-focus'.

Gear: EOS-M, 70-300mm 4-5.6, 550EX & YN-560

Comment: Just about every camera focuses fully open to avoid precisely this problem - does the EOS M really do something different?

Comment: Yes that's what my older camera did, but he EOS-M shows the effect on exposure in the liveview, WYSIWYG I guess. Maybe there is a setting to turn this off? If there is I can't find it...

Comment: This "feature" is generally known as exposure compensation, and it does seem that it [can't be switched off on the EOS-M](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=3648.125) :-(

Comment: @PhilipKendall err... exposure _simulation_.  Compensation is the dialing-in-the-EVs thingie.

Comment: Technically speaking, the EOS M has no *viewfinder*, It only has an LCD screen. This is the primary disadvantage of the mirrorless camera concept compared to a camera with an optical TTL viewfinder. Note: there are advantages and disadvantages to every camera system and specific model. This is not an attempt to say any concept is "better" or "worse" than another. Instead it is merely an attempt to observe the differences between two different concepts.

Answer (score 7):

You need to disable exposure simulation.

The EOS M doesn't have a menu option for this but it is disabled with an ETTL flash or ETTL trigger in the hotshoe.

(actually any Canon "dedicated" flash will also communicate with the camera and disable Exp Sim)

You could also install Magic Lantern as it includes a menu option to disable Exp Sim.

Comment: Have installed magic lantern. exposure sim can be quickly disabled!